# Error even after starting mysql server with --skip-grant-tables

Tags: mysql

I have forgotten the password for mysql server. Even after starting the server with `--skip-grant-tables` I get the below error.

ER

> ROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

This is for windows.

Also I get the error even for `mysql -u root`

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do

First ensure that mysqld is not running.

```
ps aux | grep mysqld
```

if it is running. Stop it. Then,

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
mysql -u root
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is for windows. Also i get the error even for mysql -u root